# How to get value of variable from another component, not child?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

I have tried to get value of variable from component `DialogDictionariesTypesComponent` using this:

```
@ViewChild(DialogDictionariesTypesComponent, { static: false })
dialogDictionaryTypes: DialogDictionariesTypesComponent;

ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.dialogDictionaryTypes.dictionaries);
}
```

Where **DialogDictionariesTypesComponent** has:

```
public dictionaries: any[] = [];
```

Why I get an error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dictionaries' of undefined
```

Comment: Usually dialog components  opened dynamically at the portal. In this case  it's not . child and `@Viewchild` can't found it.  If so  when you  open dialog you have to store reference to  dialog component to  access it, but better  solution is use Subject which emit on close of dialog and return   expected value

Comment: Can you show your template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>When using `ViewChild` with `{static: false}` the property is available in (and after) the `ngAfterViewInit` hook</strike>

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.dialogDictionaryTypes.dictionaries);
}
```

If you really need it in the `ngOnInit`, you can set static to `true`, but be aware that if you have any structural directive surrounding your child component, it will fail.

After reading your title, I see that the component you are looking for is -not- a child. In that case you should -always- use a service and inject this service in both components.

> `ViewChild` is only used to obtain a reference of a component or `HTMLElement` instance declared inside your component's template

Also, your initial thought of accessing data from components is a bit flawed. You should never do this, because components are just used for views and interaction with the view, not for data storage. Try to keep them as dumb as possible.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class DictonaryService {
  readonly dictionaries: Dictionary[] = [];
}

@Component({

})
export class DialogDictionariesTypesComponent {
  constructor(private ds: DictionaryService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(ds.dictionaries);
  }
}


@Component({

})
export class SomeOtherComponent {
  constructor(private ds: DictionaryService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(ds.dictionaries);
  }
}
```

In this example these components will log the same dictionary array. This is however very rudimentary and you should really look into using data streams using rxjs to make your life easier (maybe even state management). Harder at first, I agree, but once you get the hang of it, your code will be very happy with you.

Comment: I am not sure if he can access not child component directly like that.

Comment: Only in `ngAfterViewInit`?

Comment: @Jony I've updated my answer to more be in line with your question :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use some service and rxjs Subject. Take a look there https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/25/angular-6-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Comment: You can say, that `@ViewChild` is used ONLY in case when one component inside another? `<app-root><app-do></app-do></app-root>` but not separated: `<app-root></app-root><app-do></app-do>`

Comment: I dont want to use ` rxjs Subject` any suggestions?

Comment: Still using a service of some sort is the way to go here. A service can still have its own state with your preferred type, not limited to an Observable. Read up on Singleton services here: https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Comment: You can  share data through  service as well

Comment: @Jony without rxjs you can not observer changes performed on the dictionaries property.

Answer (score 0):

In angular services are used to share data with components.

> Components shouldn't fetch or save data directly and they certainly
>   shouldn't knowingly present fake data. They should focus on presenting
>   data and delegate data access to a service.

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

I would create a service to stored data that I need in a different component that's not a child.

Comment: For what then exist ViewChild?

Comment: As the name suggests it's used to access child components according to your question, you are trying to access data from a component that is not a child component to the one you're in. If I may ask, are your components referenced by a separate parent component?  https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description

Depending on your situation another way to share data between components is to use the @Output decorator and emit changes to a variable that can be accessed by other components 

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/angular-7-share-component-data-with-other-components-1b91d6f0b93f